# Inserting into nested mongodb objects

Tags: mongodb

The data in this post is a hypothetical similar to a problem I’m dealing with.
I am working with Python using pymongo.
I have a document that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: "123456789",
    continent_name: "Europe",
    continent_id: "001",
    countries: [
      {
        country_name: "France",
        country_id: "011",
        cities: [
          {
            city_name: "Paris",
            city_id: "101"
          },
          {
            city_name: "Maseille",
            city_id: "102"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        country_name: "England",
        country_id: "012",
        cities: [
          {
            city_name: "London",
            city_id: "201"
          },
          {
            city_name: "Bath",
            city_id: "202"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I’ve run my data collection and received an array for cities in england, including cities already in the document, e.g. London, Bath, Manchester, Liverpool.
Given the nature of the data I am collecting, when I (infrequently) run my data collection, I want to either create a new country with its own cities aray, or replace the entire existing cities array with a new one, but have no idea how to go about it.

My current process takes place over three stages.

1. Upsert Continent document:

```
continents.update(
    {},
    {"continent_id": CONTINENT_ID, "continent_name": CONTINENT_NAME},
    upsert=True
)
```

2. Upsert Country into Continent:

```
continents.update(
    {"continent_id": CONTINENT_ID"},
    {
        "$addToSet": {
            "countries": {"country_id": COUNTRY_ID, "country_name": COUNTRY_NAME}
        }
    },
    upsert=True
)
```

3. Upsert Cities in Country

```
continents.update(
    {"continent_id": CONTINENT_ID, "countries.country_id": COUNTRY_ID},
    {
        "$set": {"countries": {"cities": [{"city_id": CITY.ID, "city_name": CITY.NAME} for CITY in CITIES]}}
    } ### THIS IS WHERE I'M STRUGGLING
)
```

However this replaces the `country_id` and `country_name` for an existing country.

**It is imperative that I overwrite the entire cities array with new cities every time.**

**UPDATE**
Tried the following:

```
continents.update_one(
    {"continent_id": data["continent_id"]},
    {"$set": {"countries.$[country].cities": [{"city_id": image["city_id"], "city_name": image["city_name"]} for city in data["cities"]]}},
    array_filters=[{"country.country_id": data["country_id"]}]
)
```

This successfully inserts the first time, but creates a duplicate the second time, resulting in another COUNTRY with the same name and id.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Keep It Simple Stupid [K.I.S.S]

I rebuilt the document to be simple.

```
[
  {
    _id: "123456789",
    continent_name: "Europe",
    continent_id: "001",
    country_name: "France",
    country_id: "011",
    cities: [
      {
        city_name: "Paris",
        city_id: "101"
      },
      {
        city_name: "Maseille",
        city_id: "102"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: "987654321",
    continent_name: "Europe",
    continent_id: "001",
    country_name: "England",
    country_id: "012",
    cities: [
      {
        city_name: "London",
        city_id: "201"
      },
      {
        city_name: "Bath",
        city_id: "202"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I can just do the following:

```
countries.update_one(
    {"continent_id": data["continent_id"], "country_id": data["country_id"]},
    {"$set": {
        "continent_id": data["continent_id"],
        "continent_name": data["continent_name"],
        "country_id": data["country_id"],
        "country_name": data["country_name"],
        "images": [
            {"city_id": city["city_id"], "city_name": city["city_name"]}
            for city in data["cities"]
        ]
    }
)
```